# from selenium import webdriver ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium'

Tags: python, selenium

I am writing some python code in Anaconda Jupyter Notebook. When i press run everything is working fine, but when i save the .py file local on my computer it is not working. What can be the error. Could it be import:

```
from selenium import webdriver 
import time
```

Do i need to set a path to selenium folder and if I do, how?

I get this error when i run it with IDLE

```
from selenium import webdriver
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium'
```

If i just click on .py file it closes immediately

Answer (score 0):

you need install selenium

```
pip install selenium
```